# Need help understanding this PWM Generator

Tags: pwm, matlab, simulink

[image: PWM Generator]

From what I was told, this is a PWM generator. I am not exactly sure how this works. Can someone explain to me how this works? Whats the use of the repeating sequence and sine wave going into the relational operator? etc.

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing the parameters of your "repeating sequence"s and sine wave

Answer (score 1):

Sine wave and a repeating wave generates waves of respective nature continuously. They are fed to a relational operator. This relational operator compares both the input values and outputs TRUE(high) if sine wave magnitude is more than the repeating wave magnitude else FALSE(low). The NOT gate generates the complement of these. They are fed to a MUX. Its output is series of TRUE/FALSE (high/low) values based on the input sine and repeating wave values.

Probably the repeating1, 2 and 3 are of different of different frequencies and duty cycle  and so PWM waves of different frequencies and duty cycle

Answer (score 0):

One conventional way of generating a PWM signal is to generate a ramp signal (as shown on your diagram) and comparing to the level of an input signal (in this case a sinewave).

The input signal range should ideally be in the same range as the ramp.

Now when the input signal is below the ramp the comparator is in one state, and when it's below it's in the other.  You now have a pulse train with width proportional to the level of the input signal. In your case you would have a pulse train with width varying sinusoidally.

This can be done digitally too, with a counter and digital comparator.  Here's a picture of how this works:
[image]